# Evaluation if conditional statement on ST Visual Developer with Cosmic for STM8

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm8

I am using STVD IDE to write code for STM8 the compiler I am using is Cosmic STM8 C compiler and the standard peripheral library provided for STM8.

The problem I have is while evaluating an `if` statement for an input pin, when evaluation the `if` statement with `== 1` or `== SET` as shown below the condition is never met despite measuring high (3.3V) on the actual input itself

```
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) == SET)
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) == 1)
```

if the condition is `== 0` or `== RESET` like the below code the code behaves properly, and the condition is evaluated successfully.

```
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) == RESET)
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) == 0)
```

I managed to make a workaround that by making the condition `!= 0` or `!= RESET` as shown below it is evaluated successfully and the code behaves properly, but I don't really understand why it works with  `!= 0` or `!= SET` and not with `== 0` or `== RESET`, does it has anything to do with the compiler?

```
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) != RESET)
if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2) != 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- Did you check the actual return value of `GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_2)` when the pin is high? I'd expect it to be non-zero _and not 1_. Presumably it is the value of `GPIO_PIN2`. Please [edit] your question with the result of your debug/experiment, verifying or falsifying this assumption, and we will be happy to write an actual answer.

Comment: @busybee you are correct that the return value is `GPIO_PIN2`, but it is not unreasonable for the OP to expect `SET` or `RESET` since the return type is `BitStatus` an enum typedef with only those two values. Looking at the source, it is a long-standing bug in the library where the result of the bitmask is simply cast to `BitStatus`.  I'd like to be surprised, but this is ST's code, and nothing surprises me anymore about that!

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behaviour bug in `GPIO_ReadInputPin()` as described at https://community.st.com/t5/stm8-mcus/stm8-library-bug-gpio-readinputpin/td-p/490178

The implementation:

```c
BitStatus GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, GPIO_Pin_TypeDef GPIO_Pin) 
{
  return ((BitStatus)(GPIOx->IDR & (vu8)GPIO_Pin)); 
}
```

is severely flawed.  It should be:

```c
BitStatus GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, GPIO_Pin_TypeDef GPIO_Pin) 
{
  return (GPIOx->IDR & (vu8)GPIO_Pin) == 0 ?
         RESET :
         SET;
}
```

for `GPIO_PIN_2`, the original requires the expression `(BitSatus)Ox04 == SET`, which will not happen.  You cannot cast an integer to an enum successfully if that integer value is not represented in the enum, the result is undefined.  Some compilers might coerce the value to one of the enumerated values, but I would expect the value to remain 0x04 and so not match either `SET` or `RESET`.

My advice in any event would be *code defensively* and always compare for *inequality with zero* or equivalent (such as `RESET` in this case).  The reason being that a `false` is always zero while *all* non-zero values are regarded as `true`, making explicit comparison with 1 unsafe. So your final *working* solution would be the advised solution as it is proof against the kind of bug in this case which may be out of your control.

So in general, code defensively by using `x != 0` or `x == 0` (or simply `x` and `!x` with implicit conversion to Boolean) over `x == 1` or `x != 1` so that you only ever test for zero or non-zero rather than a specific non-zero value.  Testing a known zero valued symbol such as `RESET` is OK, but unnecessary and another potential for error if you make the wrong assumptions about the symbol's zeroness.

Astonishingly, this issue remains uncorrected at https://documentation.help/STM8S-STM8A/stm8s__gpio_8c_source.html

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot and clears everything up.

Comment: You are welcome, but would remind you of https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment with respect to the _When shouldn't I comment?_ part.